# Call a third Form from the first Form

Tags: c#, forms

I have a "beginner" simple situation here:

i have my main form with a button calling a second form (form2) whit mainform parameters as:

In Form1 :

button_click

```
Form2 F2 = new Form2(this);
F2.Show();
```

In Form2 :

```
public class Form2(Form1 form1)    
InitializeComponent(); mainForm = form1;
```

Ok now i have a Form3(Form1 form1) and i want to call it (show) from Form2 but when i put the code in the second form (Form2):

button_click

```
Form3 F3 = new Form3(this);    
F3.Show();
```

gives me an error . I tried putting (Form1 form1) instead of (this) but it doesnt work.

How to call Form3 form Form2?

Comment: What is the error exactly?

Comment: Drop the `Form1 ` from the call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attemps show a lack of understanding how parameters are passed to methods, it's not strictly related to winforms.

Anyway, you have declared a `Form3` that takes an instance of `Form1` as a parameter. If inside your `Form2` code you do `new Form3(this)` the `this` will reference the instance of the object you're currently in, which is an instance of `Form2`, and it does not match the form signature.

Also, you can't pass a parameter to a method declaring it's type like you did - `new Form3(Form1 form1)` - as it does not make any sense and it is not valid syntax.

Since you have stored the `Form1` instance reference in a local variable `mainForm` and your `Form3` requires an instance of `Form1` you should instantiate it like this: `new Form3(mainForm)`. Make sure the `mainForm` variable is accessible from where your instantiate `Form3`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Form3 F3 = new Form3(mainForm);    
F3.Show();
```